# Problemas no envio do e-Social: Assinatura do evento inválida

Tags: php, xml, api, assinatura

Usando `RobRichards`, estou tentando obter uma resposta positiva no envio do `XML`, mas sempre acusa a mensagem:

> "Assinatura do evento inválida. Ações Sugeridas: Verificar se houve
>   alteração do evento após a assinatura. Verificar a validade da
>   assinatura."

Já tentei diversas formas tanto da assinatura como no envio, mas sem sucesso.

Meu script PHP:

```php
<?php
    use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityDSig;
    use RobRichards\XMLSecLibs\XMLSecurityKey;

    $repository = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    require $repository.'src\XMLSecurityKey.php';
    require $repository.'src\XMLSecurityDSig.php';
    require $repository.'src\XMLSecEnc.php';
    require $repository.'src\Utils/XPath.php';
    $array['xsd'] = 'evtInfoEmpregador';
    $array['pem'] = $repository.'ARQUIVO.pem';
    $array['pass'] = 'PASSWORD';
    $array['xml'] = 'S1000.xml';
    $array['xml-assinado'] = 'S1000-assinado.xml';

    function connWsEsocial($array){
        $options = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer'       => false,
                'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true,
                'capture_peer_cert' => true
            ),
            'http' => array('timeout' => 5) //seconds
        );
        $stream = stream_context_create($options);
        $paramsSoap = array(
            'encoding'           => 'UTF-8',
            'local_cert'         => $array['pem'],
            'passphrase'         => $array['pass'],
            'cache_wsdl'         => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'exceptions'         => true,
            'trace'              => true,
            "use"                => SOAP_ENCODED,
            "style"              => SOAP_RPC,
            'stream_context'     => $stream,
            'soap_version'       => SOAP_1_1,
            'connection_timeout' => 25 //seconds
        );
        try{
            $connSoap = new SoapClient($array['wsdl'], $paramsSoap);
            return $connSoap;
        } catch(SoapFault $fault){
            trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
            exit;
        }
    }

    function sendXmlEsocial($xml, $connSoap, $type){
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance','xsi');
        $headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema','xsd');
        $headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope','soap');
        $connSoap->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
        switch($type){
            case 'envio':
                $sXml = '<EnviarLoteEventos xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_0"><loteEventos>'.$xml.'</loteEventos></EnviarLoteEventos>';
                $paramSoapCall = new SoapVar($sXml, XSD_ANYXML);
                $response = $connSoap->EnviarLoteEventos($paramSoapCall);
                $objXml = simplexml_load_string($response->EnviarLoteEventosResult->any);
                print '<textarea style="height:300px; width:70%;">'; print_r($objXml); print '</textarea><br>';
                return $objXml->retornoEnvioLoteEventos->dadosRecepcaoLote->protocoloEnvio;
            break;

            case 'consulta':
                $paramSoapCall = new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML);
                $response = $connSoap->ConsultarLoteEventos($paramSoapCall);
                $objXml = simplexml_load_string($response->ConsultarLoteEventosResult->any);
                print '<textarea style="height:300px; width:70%;">'; print_r($objXml); print '</textarea><br>';
            break;
        }
    }

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($array['xml']);
    $objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig();
    $objDSig->setCanonicalMethod(XMLSecurityDSig::C14N);
    $objDSig->addReference($doc, XMLSecurityDSig::SHA256, array('http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature', 'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315'));
    $objKey = new XMLSecurityKey(XMLSecurityKey::RSA_SHA256, array('type'=>'private'));
    $objKey->passphrase = $array['pass'];
    $objKey->loadKey($array['pem'], TRUE);
    $objDSig->sign($objKey);
    $objDSig->add509Cert(file_get_contents($array['pem']));
    $objDSig->appendSignature($doc->documentElement);
    $doc->save($array['xml-assinado'], LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    /*$xml = str_replace('<?xml version="1.0"?>', '', file_get_contents($array['xml-assinado']));*/
    $xml = file_get_contents($array['xml-assinado']);
    print '<textarea style="height:300px; width:70%;">'.$xml.'</textarea><br>';

    $array['wsdl'] = 'https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl'; //HOMOLOGAÇÃO
    $connSoap = connWsEsocial($array);
    $xmlLote = '<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1"><envioLoteEventos grupo="1"><ideEmpregador><tpInsc>1</tpInsc><nrInsc>CNPJ</nrInsc></ideEmpregador><ideTransmissor><tpInsc>1</tpInsc><nrInsc>CNPJ</nrInsc></ideTransmissor><eventos><evento Id="ID1">'.$xml.'</evento></eventos></envioLoteEventos></eSocial>';
    $protocolo = sendXmlEsocial($xmlLote, $connSoap, 'envio');

    $array['wsdl'] = 'https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/consultarloteeventos/WsConsultarLoteEventos.svc?singleWsdl'; //HOMOLOGAÇÃO
    $connSoap = connWsEsocial($array);
    $cXml = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/consulta/retornoProcessamento/v1_1_0"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><v1:ConsultarLoteEventos><v1:consulta><eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/consulta/retornoProcessamento/v1_0_0"><consultaLoteEventos><protocoloEnvio>'.$protocolo.'</protocoloEnvio></consultaLoteEventos></eSocial></v1:consulta></v1:ConsultarLoteEventos></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';
    sendXmlEsocial($cXml, $connSoap, 'consulta');
?>
```

---

**EDIÇÃO**

Segue XML:

```xml
<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v02_05_00">
  <evtInfoEmpregador Id="ID1071163060000002019030716513500000">
    <ideEvento>
      <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
      <procEmi>1</procEmi>
      <verProc>V020500</verProc>
    </ideEvento>
    <ideEmpregador>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>07116306</nrInsc>
    </ideEmpregador>
    <infoEmpregador>
      <inclusao>
        <idePeriodo>
          <iniValid>2019-03</iniValid>
        </idePeriodo>
        <infoCadastro>
          <nmRazao>RAZAO SOCIAL</nmRazao>
          <classTrib></classTrib>
          <natJurid></natJurid>
          <indCoop>0</indCoop>
          <indConstr>0</indConstr>
          <indDesFolha>0</indDesFolha>
          <indOptRegEletron>0</indOptRegEletron>
          <indEntEd>N</indEntEd>
          <indEtt>N</indEtt>
          <contato>
            <nmCtt>NOME CONTADOR</nmCtt>
            <cpfCtt>23665896588</cpfCtt>
            <foneFixo>1123652365</foneFixo>
            <email>email@contador.com.br</email>
          </contato>
          <softwareHouse>
            <cnpjSoftHouse>2345345243523535</cnpjSoftHouse>
            <nmRazao>SOFTWARE HOUSE LTDA</nmRazao>
            <nmCont>NOME COMPLETO</nmCont>
            <telefone>1123652365</telefone>
            <email>email@softwarehouse.com.br</email>
          </softwareHouse>
          <infoComplementares>
            <situacaoPJ>
              <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>
            </situacaoPJ>
          </infoComplementares>
        </infoCadastro>
      </inclusao>
    </infoEmpregador>
  </evtInfoEmpregador>
</eSocial>
```

E o XML Lote é esse:

```xml
<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1">
  <envioLoteEventos grupo="1">
    <ideEmpregador>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>07116306</nrInsc>
    </ideEmpregador>
    <ideTransmissor>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>07116306000156</nrInsc>
    </ideTransmissor>
    <eventos>
      <evento Id="ID1071163060000002019030716513500000">XML ASSINADO</evento>
    </eventos>
  </envioLoteEventos>
</eSocial>
```

Esse é o XML já assinado:

```xml
<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1">
  <envioLoteEventos grupo="1">
    <ideEmpregador>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>07116306</nrInsc>
    </ideEmpregador>
    <ideTransmissor>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>07116306000157</nrInsc>
    </ideTransmissor>
    <eventos>
      <evento Id="ID1071163060000002019030716513500000">
        <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v02_05_00">
          <evtInfoEmpregador Id="ID1071163060000002019030716513500000">
            <ideEvento>
              <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
              <procEmi>1</procEmi>
              <verProc>v02_05_00</verProc>
            </ideEvento>
            <ideEmpregador>
              <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
              <nrInsc>07116306</nrInsc>
            </ideEmpregador>
            <infoEmpregador>
              <inclusao>
                <idePeriodo>
                  <iniValid>2019-03</iniValid>
                </idePeriodo>
                <infoCadastro>
                  <nmRazao>RAZAO SOCIAL</nmRazao>
                  <classTrib>01</classTrib>
                  <natJurid>2062</natJurid>
                  <indCoop>0</indCoop>
                  <indConstr>0</indConstr>
                  <indDesFolha>0</indDesFolha>
                  <indOptRegEletron>0</indOptRegEletron>
                  <indEntEd>N</indEntEd>
                  <indEtt>N</indEtt>
                  <contato>
                    <nmCtt>NOME COMPLETO</nmCtt>
                    <cpfCtt>12345678999</cpfCtt>
                    <foneFixo>1134684850</foneFixo>
                    <email>email@contato.com.br</email>
                  </contato>
                  <softwareHouse>
                    <cnpjSoftHouse>01234567890000</cnpjSoftHouse>
                    <nmRazao>softwareHouse LTDA</nmRazao>
                    <nmCont>NOME COMPLETO</nmCont>
                    <telefone>1123652365</telefone>
                    <email>email@softwareHouse.com.br</email>
                  </softwareHouse>
                  <infoComplementares>
                    <situacaoPJ>
                      <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>
                    </situacaoPJ>
                  </infoComplementares>
                </infoCadastro>
              </inclusao>
            </infoEmpregador>
          </evtInfoEmpregador>
          <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
              <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>HZxjQxHchEUvK6A1CH+3OOUsgze5Czdw+1.....</DigestValue>
              </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>ihjBzQZ9Q4DXQNxR8UZR/fKSCEnQDOVyW+WD4ztGZztNoR8s9oySx+6CV1B+SSSIXvMQWHIzr.....</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
              <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>MIIH/jCCBeagAw.....
  </envioLoteEventos>
</eSocial>
```

Comment: Por favor, poste o XML que você está usando para assinar e enviar (`$array['xml'] = 'S1000.xml';`), e poste também o trecho de código onde você substitui os placheholders `CNPJ` e `ID1`, na variável `$xmlLote` usada na função `sendXmlEsocial()`.

Comment: Pedro Gaspar, acabei de postar os dois já com os valores devidos.

Comment: Eu editei sua pergunta e coloquei os XMLs lá. Exclua depois a resposta que você postou aqui, por favor. Você pode colocar também como ficou o XML do evento depois da assinatura? Esse ID fo evento você está colocando na mão em algum momento ou a informação já vem preechida antes da assinatura? Você faz alguma alteração no XML do evento assinado depois da assinatura?

Comment: Peço desculpas pela ignorância. Sou novo e estou aprendendo a mexer aqui. 

Eu não faço alteração no XML não e como eu tenho bom banco de dados para armazenar as informações dos clientes que faremos o envio, eu faço o select no banco, monto o XML e depois utilizo a função para assinatura. Depois do XML montado, antes de assinar, eu não mexo mais nele. O ID eu monto de acordo com as especificações do e-Social. Como ele pede datahora, eu monto ele na hora, antes de montar o XML e o adiciono. Depois com o XML pronto, envio para assinar. Vou postar um XML com a assinatura.

Comment: Tranquilo Leonardo, não precisa se desculpar. Sem querer ser chato, mas, ficou faltando um pedaço nesse último XML (assinado) que você postou... Coloque o XML completo, por favor, para podemos analisar melhor o problema!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu analisei o seu código e os XMLs e tudo parece estar certo, mas aí eu percebi que o problema parece estar nessa linha aqui:

```
   $doc->save($array['xml-assinado'],
              LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Primeiro que, ao consultar a documentação do método [`DOMDocument::save`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php), verifiquei que esse método só aceita a opção `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG`, então as duas outras opções (`LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` e `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD`) estão de bobeira aí.

Mas o que parece estar causando o problema de fato é a opção `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG`, que, segundo a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php), expande tags vazias:

> **LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG**
>   Expand empty tags (e.g. `<br/>` to `<br></br>`)

No XML do evento do eSocial não há tags vazias, mas na assinatura há as tags `<CanonicalizationMethod />`, `<SignatureMethod />`, `<Transform />` e `<DigestMethod />`, então, o documento assinado está sendo alterado, quando essa opção é usada.

Veja que no exemplo de uso básico da biblioteca [XMLSecLibs](https://github.com/robrichards/xmlseclibs#basic-usage) do Rob Richards, o método `DOMDocument::save` é usado sem nenhuma opção:

```
   // Save the signed XML
   $doc->save('./path/to/signed.xml');
```

Altere então essa linha que comentei para:

```
   $doc->save($array['xml-assinado']);
```

que o problema deve ser resolvido.

Comment: Realmente o problema foi resolvido com a substituição dessa linha. Quero agradecer a todos pela ajuda prestada. Projeto em funcionamento.

Comment: @LeonardoDelgado, que bom que funcionou! Mas, a melhor forma de agradecer por uma resposta é marcando ela como aceita, clicando no sinal de visto (✓). Mas faça isso apenas se alguma resposta tiver respondido sua dúvida original. Quando atingir 15 pontos de reputação também poderá [votar a favor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) de uma resposta ou pergunta. Veja: [Alguém me respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Por que votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: Feito! Grato pela atenção e colaboração de todos!

Answer (score -2):

Tive o mesmo problema de **Assinatura do evento inválida**, adotei este item da resposta do Pedro Gaspar

```
$doc->save($xml_assinado,LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

E também coloquei o item FALSE nesta parte para remover os prefixos **"ds:"** do XML assinado

```
$objDSig = new XMLSecurityDSig(FALSE);
```